# How to get subset of a Seurat object based on metadata?

Tags: seurat

I have a Seurat object in which the meta.data include a column name "predicted_cell_type". The values of this column include "0:CD8 T cell",  "1:CD4 T cell", "2:spinous cell", etc.

I would like to extract the "0:CD8 T cell" from the object and use the following command:

```
subset(skin, subset = skin@meta.data[['predicted_cell_type']] == '0:CD8 T cell')
```

but it gives the following error:

```
Error in FetchData.Seurat(object = object, vars = unique(x = expr.char[vars.use]),  : 
  None of the requested variables were found:
```

And if I use

```
subset(skin, subset = predicted_cell_type == '0:CD8 T cell')
```

It gives

```
Error: No cells found
```

Do you know what is the correct command to do this?

With many thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to address this.

The most common way is using the objects Idents:

```
Idents(skin) <- "predicted_cell_type"
skin_subset <- subset(skin, idents = "0:CD8 T cell")
```

For the code you provided, I believe using quotations around the column name will work:

```
skin_subset <- subset(skin, subset = "predicted_cell_type" == "0:CD8 T cell")
```

Lastly, you can use the colnames and metadata

```
skin_subset <- skin[ , rownames(skin@meta.data)[skin@meta.data$predicted_cell_type == `0:CD8 T cell`]]
```